# Change rotation if current visible pages of UIPageViewController don't support current orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to get the device to rotate if the user skims on a `UIPageViewController` to a new view controller that doesn't support the current interface orientation. I'd like to get the more or less the same behavior as if an VC is pushed modally.

Example: The current VC of an `UIPageViewController` supports all interface orientations and the user skims to the next VC which should only be displayed in landscape.

I used the default Page-Base-Application-Template for testing and implemented the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of the DataViewController as follows:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    }

    if ([self.dataObject isEqualToString:@"February"]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

My expectation was that if I skim to the view controller for february the screen would rotate to landscape but it stays in portrait. The interesting part is that the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is called and NO is returned if I skim to the february-VC.

I also played around with checking the orientation in the `RootViewController` but without any luck.

I'm out of any ideas now.
Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The interesting part is that the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is called and NO is returned if
>   I skim to the february-VC

In that case I would suggest that your only approach will be to subclass UIPageViewController. Clearly it knows what it thinks the reply to `shouldAutorotate` should be, and you disagree with that reply, so you'll need to offer a different reply.

I am not surprised to hear that UIPageViewController behaves like this, though - after all, UINavigationController works the same way: if you push a view controller onto the navigation controller's stack and that view controller does not permit the current orientation of the device, the interface does *not* rotate to an orientation that the view controller does permit. I work around that by presenting a view (what used to be called a modal view), which does force the device to rotate.